# Syntax error on view with if else if branch

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view where I am trying to detect which group a logged in user is a member off and displaying an appropriate page, or redirecting them back to the login screen.

No matter how I try to write this, I continue to get a syntax error. Nothing more clear than that.

My view at the moment is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def loginCheck(request):
    if User.objects.filter(pk=userId, groups__name='red').exists():
        return render(request, 'colors/red.html', {})
    elif User.objects.filter(pk=userId, groups__name='blue').exists()
        return render(request, 'colors/blue.html', {})
    elif User.objects.filter(pk=userId, groups__name='staff').exists()
        return redirect('/site/staff/')
    else:
        return redirect('/site/login/')
```

Is this approach sound? Am I missing an obvious mistake?

Comment: You are missing a **`:`** at the end of ***`elif...`*** statements

Answer (score 0):

You are omitted two colons at the end of middle two statements

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the colon `:` at the end of the elif lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@permission_required` decorator that automatically does what you need: It'll redirect the user to the login page if it doesn't have the appropiate permission. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator).

(As many people pointed out, you're missing a colon in the `elif` statement, but it's much better to use the decorator so you do it more djangoish)